# How many emails can I use in the input type text field and How to pass that multiple emails from one page to another without using session in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, input

## 1st issue

I have more the one thousand emails and I am entering manually in the input type text field. I mean just copy from excel sheet and paste in the text field.

Just want to know, 
1) Can I add more than one thousand email in the single input text? If yes then how many emails I can add?

## 2nd Issue

There are thousands of email in the field and I have to send that email from one page to another page without using session.

**Page1.php**

```
<form action="process.php?key=addemail" method="post">
<input type="text" name="emailtemplate[]" placeholder="Enter email name" class="form-control">
 <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
<textarea name="mailbody" id="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="addmail" value="Add mail" class="v-btn v-btn-primary">
</form>
```

**Page2**

```
function addemail($conn)
{
  $to=$_POST['emailtemplate'];
  $subject =$_POST['subject'];
  $mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];
  sendMail($to, $subject, $mailbody );
}
```

I am trying to cheeck `echo $to` but i am getting error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion  on line 173
Array
```

Would you help me in this?

Comment: $_POST['emailtemplate'] is an array... use a for loop to iterate through that array ...

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Patricks, You means to say I have to used for loop in page 2. right?

Comment: Because What I am doing is, After getting email on 2nd page, I have to separate it and sending email to each email id

Comment: Sending a single `mail` command to 1000+ recipients, jeeez, goodbye server, run the code and then take a holiday somewhere far away...... .

Comment: Why does it need to be an `<input>`? Simply make it a `<textarea>` and then explode the resultant `$_POST` string on page2.php

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Martin. You mean to say I have to use <textarea> instated of <input> ??

Answer (score 0):

Your `addemail` function could look something like this in order for things to work:

```
function addemail( $conn ){
    $subject = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $mailbody = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'mailbody', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    foreach( $_POST['emailtemplate'] as $t ){
        $recipient = filter_var( $t, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
        sendMail( $recipient, $subject, $mailbody );
    }
}
```

Note that this is untested. I don't see the parameter `$conn` used for instance... But $_POST['emailtemplate'] is an array, you need to iterate through that. I also filtered your input from the form like you always should. That way you're a lot safer from any code injections...